# Readlink not working properly on SSH remote terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal, find

I have below command to find any folder/file by name "Zero1" or "zero1" (case insensitive) in the whole directory structure from `public_html` after I login to remote terminal through `ssh`.

```
find . -iname "Zero1" -exec readlink -f {} + | tee Zero1.txt
```

But if there are multiple folders matching the criteria(there should be that's why I am using this), then it breaks saying `extra operand .... Try readlink --help for more information`.

Also it doesn't find the file named "Zero1_Module.xml" which is in the structure and matching the criteria (name should contain Zero1).

Why is that ? How can I overcome this and still use this same command ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the option *iname* means something different: according to [the Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find),

> **-iname pattern**
>
> Like -name, but the match is case insensitive

However, the *pattern* you provided is for *an exact match*. If you want wo find a match for every file which begins with *zero1* (case **in**sensitive), you should use:

```
 find . -iname 'zero1*'
```

(no need to use capitals, since the match is case insensitive): the asterisk assures you there will be a match for any file beginning with *zero1* (case insensitive).

Second, the *exec* clause should be written as follows:

```
find . -iname 'zero1*' -exec sh -c 'readlink -f $0  | tee Zero1.txt' {} \;
```

Or

```
find . -iname 'zero1' -exec sh -c 'readlink -f $0 | tee -a Zero1.txt' {} \;
```

The exec clause should (nearly) always be terminated by *\;*, and the invocation *sh -c '...'* is needed to prevent the shell from breaking the pipe; lastly, the correspondence *{} -> $0* is needed to pass arguments to a command surrounded by *'...'*, because, once again, the shell does not interpret the commands within the apices, hence it cannot substitute the real file name for *{}*. Thus we need to pass the filename to the *'...'* commnad via an external way.

Please let me know whether the error message concerning *readlink* persists after this try.

Comment: `su -c` gives permission denied error, also I cannot have `sudo` password for remote ssh. What should I do next ?

Comment: I did change the command accordingly and ran this one `find . -iname 'MSP*' -exec sh -c 'readlink -f $0 + | tee MSP.txt' {} \;` (there is files and folders starting with "MSP"), but still gives error `extra operand `+'
Try `readlink --help' for more information.`.

Comment: Yes it wasn't necessary to have `+`, after removing it, the command works fine. Thanks a lot. You can upvote my question if you found it worthy.

Comment: Just one more thing, with `+` I thought it was appending the result and writing it to text file, so how can I write the output of this command to text file ? Right now it is only writing last line of output to text file.